# SqlBulkCopy drops global temp table then fails to perform insert

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I use `SqlBulkCopy` to populate tables in a very fast and efficient manner. Previously, I created permanent tables with "temporary names" (named something like Temp_1239128213129873912873), but it always bothered me. Even though obviously a temp table de-facto, it's still de-jure a permanent table, and is therefore technically a schema modification in production. Also, if the process crashes, the clean up code doesn't run and these tables stay around; after a year, there will be 5-6 of these accumulated.

I decided to try switching to global temp tables. When I did so, I started facing this weird issue where the call to `WriteToServerAsync` reported that the table isn't found, with errors like "Cannot access destination table '##temp_123871298371928739182739'"

```
string connStr = "...";
using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr); await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
using var com = new SqlCommand(sqlConnection) { CommandText = "CREATE TABLE ##temp_123871298371928739182739 (...);" }; await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connStr) { DestinationTableName = "##temp_123871298371928739182739", };
await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(sourceDataReader); // throws exception
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I debugged it, it turned out that the table gets created successfully, but somehow gets dropped inside that method. I tried creating the same table in SQL UI (SSMS for MSSQL) and the `WriteToServerAsync` worked fine. This led me to believe it's something to do with `SqlConnection` being reset when reused from connection pool.

To fix this, I kept the same `SqlConnection` for both the global temp table creation and the `WriteToServerAsync` call, and it works perfectly (both SQL Server and Azure SQL):

```
string connStr = "...";
using var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr); await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
using var com = new SqlCommand(sqlConnection) { CommandText = "CREATE TABLE ##temp_123871298371928739182739 (...);" }; await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection) { DestinationTableName = "##temp_123871298371928739182739", };
await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(sourceDataReader);
```

Answer (score -1):

**The problem is that temp tables are dropped as soon as the connection is closed, so you need to hold it open until you are finished with the table.**

You should also ideally avoid `##` global temp tables, as these can interfere with other connections using the same name. Instead use `#` local temp tables.

I note that your code does not have `using` blocks. It should really look like this:

```cs
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
    using (var com = new SqlCommand(sqlConnection) { CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #temp (...);" })
    {
         await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }

    using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection) { DestinationTableName = "#temp", })
    {
        await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(sourceDataReader);
    }

    // other stuff with temp table

    sqlConnection.Close();   // table is dropped automatically
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and answer to clarify that I'm still using a randomizer to prevent global temp table collisions. Local temp tables are not usable because they are scope specific; the `CREATE` script executes, then the local `#temp` table is dropped, **not** at connection close. Your answer is incorrect in that regard.